# How to create more than one primary key in SQLite ?How to create user name already exist validation in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, validation, android-activity, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a Registration page for Login activity, I cant create the DataBase by declaring user_name and id columns as Primary Key, If I remove the primary key in id column error exist and if I add primary key to user_name error exist also I have tried PRIMARY KEY(id, user_name) though error exist and also I tried a activity in which if I enter duplicate user name toast should appear as "User Name already exist"

I'm not inserting the id value manually, it has to be AUTO INCREMENT

Hear is my code,
**Error Exist**

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("PPP.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String see ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,user_name VARCHAR(120) PRIMARY KEY, password VARCHAR(30), category VARCHAR(30),age VARCHAR(20), height VARCHAR(20), weight VARCHAR(20))";
        db.execSQL(see);
```

**Error Exist**

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("PPP.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String see ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile(id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT ,user_name VARCHAR(120) PRIMARY KEY, password VARCHAR(30), category VARCHAR(30),age VARCHAR(20), height VARCHAR(20), weight VARCHAR(20))";
        db.execSQL(see);
```

**Error Exist**

```
db = openOrCreateDatabase("PPP.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String see ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile(id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT ,user_name VARCHAR(120), password VARCHAR(30), category VARCHAR(30),age VARCHAR(20), height VARCHAR(20), weight VARCHAR(20), PRIMARY KEY(id, user_name))";
        db.execSQL(see);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have only one primary key, but you can add UNIQUE constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name TEXT UNIQUE,
    password TEXT,
    category TEXT,
    age TEXT,
    height TEXT,
    weight TEXT
)
```

(Note: you don't need AUTOINCREMENT to get an [autoincrementing ID](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), and the column length [is not checked](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) anyway.)

Comment: Thank you very much...! But can you please tell How to declare two PRIMARY KEY in my query...?

Comment: It is not possible to have two primary keys.